# i am unable to create debug log. Getting error

Tags: debug-logs

When i try to create debug log i am getting below error. Even i have deleted all user trace flags and checked in dev console also by querying user trace flags.

Having an active trace flag triggers debug logging. You have 590 MB of the maximum 250 MB of debug logs. Before you can edit trace flags, delete some debug logs.

Answer (score 1):

You have hit the limit of maximum size of debug log. You need to delete them to get some space.

You can also run this query to get them in bulk and delete them

Use the following query in the Developer Console to access the TraceFlag object:

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, ExpirationDate, TracedEntityId, ApexCode, ApexProfiling,  Callout, Database, System, Validation, Visualforce, Workflow FROM TraceFlag
```

***Be sure to select the 'Use Tooling API' checkbox before executing the query***

*[Bulk delete trace flags through Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231445&type=1)*

Comment: Thanks Tushar. it worked ..Also by deleting apexlogs.

Comment: @VinothiniMurugesh Then you can accept this answer and close the question.

Comment: This is not trace flags issue. You'll just need to delete logs, in dev console execute: SELECT Id FROM ApexLog, then delete all rows (Use shift key to select all rows).
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194045&type=1

Answer (score 0):

You can define Log Level as info which are not needed to trace, like this

[image: Log Level]